# Atlas images wrong size on iPad iOS 9

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2, ios9

Since upgrading to iOS 9 I have this strange issue with image atlases in my SpriteKit game.
In my game I have a StartScene, a MenuScene and a GameScene.

In all 3 scenes I am using atlases for my enemies so I can animate them. All worked fine on all devices but since upgrading iOS 9 it causes me issues on iPads.

On my iPad when I launch the game the enemies in StartScene are about 3 times as big as they should be. Whats strange is that when I move to menuScene or gameScene the enemies are normal size.
When I tell my game to launch straight into MenuScene I have the same problem, enemies are way to big until I change to another scene. 
This happened as soon as I run my game on iOS 9 and even after I upgraded to swift 2 and Xcode 7 I am still having this issue.

Anyone seeing this too, I have no clue what could cause this and how to fix it. Is this just a terrible iOS 9 bug?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Also seeing this bug, haven't found a fix yet.

Comment: So frustrating, haven't found a fix yet too.

Comment: see my comment below. If you change deployment target to iOS 9.0 it goes away. its weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was purely an iOS 9 bug and I believe was fixed. The initial code for my game was not doing any SKScene scaling, I did it all manually for every device, which was a terrible idea. Since asking this question I have change the way my scenes are scaled (AspectFill) so I am not 100% sure if this bug is still occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I saw there's a new option in the Xcode assets. If you click on the plus sign and select Sprite Kit Asset, you may fix the problem.

Comment: Hey, thank you. I actually tried this already, no difference. The strange thing this only happens on iPads and only on the first Scene thats presented.

Comment: That's definitely a bug. I had miscellaneous resources in an atlas. Ended up moving them in the asset and treating them as single resources. Experiencing that even in all the scenes not only the first one.

Comment: For me this only happens on the first scene, as soon as I move to another one its all good. I am actually just on the phone to apple because its ridiculous. Its not like Android where nobody upgrades, in about 5 days at least 60% of users have iOS 9. I am having some other issues too, are you experiencing them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524051/swift-2-spritekit-issues

Comment: Interesting note, if I change my deployment target to iOS 9.0 the problem is gone.

Comment: yeah of course not, I was just saying. I actually made a TSI with apple to get this sorted. Ill keep you posted. I assume you didn't find any fixes?

Comment: its pretty ridiculous. I understand that you might have to adjust code etc when a new iOS and language update is released. This is not a code issue tho.