# Swift 2 SpriteKit issues

Tags: swift2

So I am having some issues with my spriteKit game since upgrading to iOS 9 and even after upgrading to Swift 2. I mentioned 1 here [Atlas images wrong size on iPad iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505572/atlas-images-wrong-size-on-ipad-ios-9/32517899#32517899)

However I am having 2 more issues I cannot fix.

1)

All my particle effects dont work anymore. This is the code I use and they are just not showing up anymore. If I just use SKEmitterNode than it works, but I prefer to add the SKEmitterNode to a SKEffectNode as it blends much better with backgrounds etc.
This is the code.

```
let particlesPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Thrusters", ofType: "sks")!
let particles = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(particlesPath) as! SKEmitterNode
let particleEffects = SKEffectNode() //blends better with background when moving

particleEffects.zPosition = 20
particleEffects.position = CGPointMake(0, -50)
particleEffects.addChild(particles)

addChild(particleEffects)
```

I read this 
http://forum.iphonedev.tv/t/10-8-skeffectnode-or-xcode-7-or-my-issue/669 
and it claims it was fixed, but it wasn't.

2)

My Game Center banners when I log in or when an achievement pops are now using the portrait banner, even though my game is in landscape. Therefore banners only cover half the top screen. It looks so bad and since there is no actually code for banners I dont even know where to start.

Anyone else facing these issues, its frustrating. 
Thanks for any help or support.

Comment: I don't use a lot of particles, but those I've got are working fine. Experiencing some GC bugs too, but I'm not sure if that's due to ios9

Comment: yeah the particle problems only happens if you add the SKEmitterNode to an SKEffectNode. I assume in your case your are not doing that. Could you explain what sort of GC bugs you are experiencing? Is the banner bug I have 1 of them?

Comment: I fixed the problem by manually removing all pending turn based matches manually from my test devices. Matches didn't behave correctly, the had wrong statuses and participants info.

Comment: fair enough. Is your game in landscape ? If so are your banners also messed up?

Comment: no, it's in portrait. Banners seems to be fine.

Comment: yeah. Is it possible to quickly put your game into landscape and see if it still uses the portrait banner?, Thats what seems to be happening to me. Thanks

Comment: I've got the same particle effect issue using obj c. I'm not even using an effect node. Just adding the SKEmitterNode to the scene and the effects are no longer showing up.

Comment: Really? Thats actually what I had to do to fix my issues, just removed the SKEffect Node and just using an SKEmiiterNode and it works again. So Strange, you found a fix yet?

Comment: I downgraded back to the previous version of swift

Comment: lol thats not the fix I am looking for.  Damn its does suck

Comment: I figured out what was causing my SKEmitterNodes to not render. I was not setting a Z position on all of my SKSpriteNodes or EmitterNodes. My background was the first child I added, then everything on top. With iOS 9, sometimes the background would render over top of the rest of my nodes but it ALWAYS rendered over my SKEmitterNodes. As soon as I changed my background to z -1 it fixed my issue.

Comment: Yeah I was actually just about to suggest this. Thats a problem I had too. I am just speaking to apple via a TSI. I will keep you posted about the SKEffectNode stuff because that still does not work.

Comment: Kyle post your z comment to -1 as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some updates to this old question. Believe it or not in regards to the particles, apple recently replied to my 1 year old BugReport to see if it is fixed in iOS 10. LOL

I heard rendering particles via a SKEffectNode way is not necessarily ideal in regards to performance and I am not using it anymore. Therefore I am not sure if the bug is still occurring with the later Xcode and iOS 9 updates or in iOS 10 beta.

In regards to the adMob banner, I simply had to change

```
let adMobBannerAdView = GADBannerView()
```

to

```
var adMobBannerAdView: GADBannerView?
```

and delay initialisation until ViewDidLoad/DidMoveToView.